# Node express server crashes when duplicate registration happens

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I have a node server up and running with an api endpoint that keeps crashing when a duplicate email is entered via postman. If a non-duplicate registration takes place, the server keeps running with no hiccups. But if a duplicate email is submitted, I do see the duplicate email error on postman:

```
{
  "code": 11000,
  "index": 0,
  "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: register.users index: email_1 dup key: { : \"atlanteavila@gmail.com\" }",
  "op": {
    "userRole": "isUser",
    "password": "yudfjadjslkafdaljj343",
    "zip": "94596",
    "state": "CA",
    "city": "Walnut Creek",
    "address2": "",
    "streetAddress": "1 fake address ",
    "phoneNumber": "(925) 555-0644",
    "email": "fake@email.com",
    "lastName": "Last",
    "firstName": "Person",
    "_id": "57e2b2e49f0de63201914616",
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

Here's the api route:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function (app) {

  router.route('/users')

  .get( function (req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'welcome!!' });
  })

  .post(function (req, res) {
    var rb = req.body;
    var user = new User();
    user.firstName = rb.firstName;
    user.lastName = rb.lastName;
    user.email = rb.email;
    user.phoneNumber = rb.phoneNumber;
    user.streetAddress = rb.streetAddress;
    user.address2 = rb.address2;
    user.city = rb.city;
    user.state = rb.state;
    user.zip = rb.zip
    user.password = rb.password;
    user.userRole = rb.userRole;


    user.save( function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        next();
      };
      res.json({ message: 'UserCreated!' });
    });
  });

  app.use('/api', router);

}
```

and the mongoose schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true,
    unique: true
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
  },
  streetAddress: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
  },
  address2: String,
  city: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
  },
  state: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
  },
  zip: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
  },
  userRole: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Finally the error on the terminal:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server/server.js`
Up and running on port 3000
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/atlanteavila/Documents/myapps/register/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/atlanteavila/Documents/myapps/register/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:164:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/atlanteavila/Documents/myapps/register/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:250:15)
    at /Users/atlanteavila/Documents/myapps/register/server/routes/signUp.js:34:11
    at /Users/atlanteavila/Documents/myapps/register/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3336:16
    at /Users/atlanteavila/Documents/myapps/register/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1932:15
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance in figuring this one out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are sending `two` responses, that's why you are getting this error

I don't think you need to use `next()` callback if you are sending the response in `save function` which will be `fail or success`.

Try to return your response after manipulation like this

```
user.save( function(err) {
      if (err) {
       return res.send(err);
      };
      return res.json({ message: 'UserCreated!' });
    });
```

Comment: This definitely solved the issue. I chose this as best answer b/c the return statement seems to be needed in both places. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are sending two responses when there is an error (which is throwing the exception). You can mitigate this by returning `next()` or returning after you call it.

```
user.save( function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return res.send(err);
  }
  res.json({ message: 'UserCreated!' });
});
```

Comment: Calling `next` isn't really useful in this situation (and possibly harmful, since it may cause an additional 404 response to be generated), as the response has already been ended by calling `res.send()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have unique: true in your schema and as you are trying to insert a duplicate record. It is violating schema validation rule. You should use exception handling for your queries and parse these errors. You can use try-catch block and If you are using promise then use catch block with each query.

To send response about the duplicate save records. Add following to your router errorhandler:

```
if (err instanceof Error && err.name === "MongoError" && err.driver) {
        if (err.code == 11000) { // unique index conflict
            return ['Resource document already exists.'];
        }
    }
```

and return it in response from the errorhandler.